# Facebook Graph API, pull information anonymously

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I know that this question could have been asked a million times before, but unfortunately I can't compile all these answers to get it working.

I want to write a PHP code that uses facebook graph API, to search for a profile (by name for example) and then grab this information to a local store. I revised facebook graph API but it makes use of OAuth and plenty of overhead tasks that I don't need. Cause simply I don't want be using the API on behalf of specific user account. I just want to use it anonymously, or even with a sample user who shouldn't necessarily be a friend with these users that I'm searching for.
I'd be grateful if somebody could tell me whether it is doable or not, or even ask me to clarify my question a little bit more :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to retrieve an access token to use the Graph API to search for users. I don't think there is a way around it. At least not with the Graph API.

Try [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#search) to use the Graph API to search for users. You'll see that they're using an access token. Trying to [search](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user) for a user without an access token will lead to the following error message.

```
{
    "error": {
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "message": "An access token is required to request this resource."
    }
}
```

**Update**:

From the Facebook Developers documentation:

"Facebook authentication enables your application to interact with the Graph API *on behalf of Facebook users*, and it provides a powerful single-sign on mechanism across Web, mobile, and desktop apps."

The [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) process isn't that complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :). can I understand like there should be a logged in user open session on the browser?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to be logged in to Facebook. At least I don't know another way to get an access token.

Answer (score 1):

Sure here's a fast way to go about getting the information you want:

```
<?PHP

define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'yourappIDhere');
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'yourFBsecretkeyhere');

function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret) {
    $args = array();
    if(isset($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id])){
        parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
    }

    ksort($args);
    $payload = '';
    foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != 'sig') {
            $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
        }
    }
    if(isset($args['sig'])){
        if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig']) {
            return null;
        }
        else
            return $args;
    }
    else
        return null;
}

$cookie = get_facebook_cookie(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_SECRET);

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php if ($cookie) { ?>
  Your user ID is <?PHP echo $cookie['uid']; ?>
<?PHP 
    $user = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/access_token=' . $cookie['access_token']))->data;

} else { 
?>
  <fb:login-button perms="email"></fb:login-button>
<?php } ?>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({appId: '<?= FACEBOOK_APP_ID ?>', status: true,
           cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After what Fair mentioned above, here's the very BASIC code you need to get the authentication setup for yourself.

HTH :)

You can change the parameters for the login button so it's not just "email" and then search by whatever else you may desire.

Comment: Actually, accessing facebook will be in the back-end, I don't need any login buttons for users lo login to facebook. I just want to grab *public* information on user's account.  Thanks for your resonse though :)